# Erro ou Bug do Delphi na Criação de Procedure

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, delphi-10

Na criação das Procedure automáticas, duplo click no componente, o Delphi XE8 e delphi-10 está tendo uma reação estranha ele mistura a nova Procedure com uma das Procedure já existente, fazendo que os nomes delas fique errada e tenho que corrigir todas. A nova Procedure fica iniciada com dois "P" ex:

**pprocedure** e a procedure já existente some um "P" ex: **rocedure**

Conforme exemplo de código abaixo:

```
pprocedure TfrmCliente.cdsMasterBeforeCancel(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  inherited;

end;

rocedure TfrmCliente.cdsMasterBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  inherited;
  if (cdsMaster.State = dsInsert)  then
     cdsMaster.FieldByName('CODIGO').AsString := '000000';

end;
```

Comment: isso ocorre ate na versão xe7 que estou usando, geralmente é algum erro que não percebemos e acabamos confundindo a IDE, da uma olhada na tecla INSERT se não foi acionada acidentalmente, aqui basta abrir e fechar "o projeto" que tudo volta ao normal!

Comment: Isso é um bug do Delphi mesmo. Eu trabalho com o XE7 e tenho esse tipo de problema quase todos os dias.

Comment: Exatamente como o @JúniorMoreira falou. Isso costuma acontecer quando você não finalizou a clausula "Uses" com ";" ou quando não finalizou com "end" a declaração de uma classe, e por ai vai. Verifica se seu código compila sem a declaração dos métodos "Automáticos"

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia Ailton, esse problema geralmente ocorre quando solicitamos a IDE para criar a Procedure automaticamente e existe algum erro de código, por exemplo um ponto e virgula faltando.

Espero ter ajudado.